# Is there built-in anyway to transform an AWS S3 pre-signed post in a pre-signed url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Given that I have an object post I got from `generate_presigned_post()` and I want to transform this into a pre-signed link, is there any way built-in **boto3**?

I know there is a method to generate the link itself `generate_presigned_url()` but this out of scope right now...

Comment: Just curious, why is `generate_presigned_url()` out of scope?

Comment: So you want to change the HTTP method of an pre signed URL?

Comment: Pre-signed URLs are 'signed' via a hash function based on all values of the input. It is not possible to change the content of the request without knowing the original Secret key, in which case you can just use `generate_presigned_url()` anyway.